# How does the plot of the output of librosa.stft work?

Tags: data-visualization, fourier-transform, matplotlib, audio

So, I have been analyzing audio data. I used the librosa package and used its .stft() function to calculate the Fourier transform of my audio data. I did the following-

```
aud,sr=librosa.load(os.path.join(path,'genres_original',i,f'{i}.00001.wav'))
aud_ft= np.abs(librosa.stft(aud, n_fft = n_fft, hop_length = hop_length,win_length=win_length)) 
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
plt.plot(aud_ft)
```

The shape of the aud_ft is (1025,1309). The plot represents frequency on the y-axis and time on the x-axis and also represents the power/amplitude of each frequency at each time sample using color.

My doubt is how does a 2d array stores frequency as well as power values?

In addition to that, I noticed some weird outputs of the plot() function.
[image]

[image: THE PLOTS AND CODE]

Why does the plot remain the same for both the cases, how do I explain this?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow could be a better venue to ask this.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

A spectrogram is a multi-variate time-series. When using matplotlib plot() to plot it, you just get each independent time-frame or frequency-band, which throws away the time/frequency relation in the signal.
Instead plot the 2d structure as a heatmap. This is easiest done using using [librosa.display.specshow](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html).